# error: function definition is not allowed here { ^

Tags: c++, jupyter-notebook

Писал код в С++ и теперь нужно его перевести в Jupyter Notebook, часть ошибок исправил, но две ошибки формата: *input_line_32:20:1: error: function definition is not allowed here { ^* не могу исправить, код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
 
struct wiel {
    int coeff;
    int pow_val;
    wiel* nowy;
};
 
class dodaj {
    wiel *wiel1, *wiel2, *wiel3;
 
public:
    dodaj() { wiel1 = wiel2 = wiel3 = NULL; }
    void dodaj_wiel();
    void wyświetl();
};
 
void dodaj::dodaj_wiel()
{
    int i, p;
    wiel *nowy1 = NULL, *koniec = NULL;
    cout << "Wpisz x :\n"; cin >> p;
    //Pierwszy Wielomian
    cout << "\nPierwszy Wielomian\n"; for (i = p; i >= 0; i--) {
        nowy1 = new wiel;
        nowy1->pow_val = p;
        cout << "Wprowadź Współczynnik dla stopnia " << i << ": "; cin >> nowy1->coeff;
        nowy1->nowy = NULL;
        if (wiel1 == NULL)
            wiel1 = nowy1;
        else
            koniec->nowy = nowy1;
        koniec = nowy1;
    }
 
    //Drugi Wielomian
    cout << "\n\nDrugi Wielomian\n"; koniec = NULL; for (i = p; i >= 0; i--) {
        nowy1 = new wiel;
        nowy1->pow_val = p;
        cout << "Wprowadź Współczynnik dla stopnia " << i << ": "; cin >> nowy1->coeff;
        nowy1->nowy = NULL;
        if (wiel2 == NULL)
            wiel2 = nowy1;
        else
            koniec->nowy = nowy1;
        koniec = nowy1;
    }
 
    //Addition Logic
    wiel *p1 = wiel1, *p2 = wiel2;
    koniec = NULL;
    while (p1 != NULL && p2 != NULL) {
        if (p1->pow_val == p2->pow_val) {
            nowy1 = new wiel;
            nowy1->pow_val = p--;
            nowy1->coeff = p1->coeff + p2->coeff;
            nowy1->nowy = NULL;
            if (wiel3 == NULL)
                wiel3 = nowy1;
            else
                koniec->nowy = nowy1;
            koniec = nowy1;
        }
        p1 = p1->nowy;
        p2 = p2->nowy;
    }
}
 
void dodaj::wyświetl()
{
    wiel* t = wiel3;
    cout << "\n\nWyprowadź wynik : ";
    while (t != NULL) {
        cout.setf(ios::showpos);
        cout << t->coeff;
        cout.unsetf(ios::showpos);
        cout << "X" << t->pow_val;
        t = t->nowy;
    }
}
int main;
{
    dodaj obj;
    obj.dodaj_wiel();
    obj.wyświetl();
}
```

Comment: Не использовал Jupyter Notebook, но он разве не для питона?

Comment: https://www.pranav.ai/cplusplus-for-jupyter

Comment: Он и для питона, и для С++. Есть онлайн компиляторы

Answer (score 1):

Скажите, как правильно объявляется функция? Например, возведения в квадрат?

Что-то типа

```
double square; { return x*x; }
```

Так? Вы посмотрите и явно скажете - что за кретин... Конечно

```
double square(double x) { retur x*x; }
```

Тогда почему вы написали объявление функции `main` как

```
int main;
{
```

В результате у вас получилось объявление переменной `main` типа `int` + код вне функции.

Скажите, вы *в самом деле* этого не видели?

Comment: int main(){...} - выдает + ещё одну ошибку такого же характера.

Comment: Где? https://ideone.com/F1s2eI Понятно, что нужно убрать нестандартный символ `ś` из названия функции, но я ж не знаю - может, у вас компилятор понимает польский :) Если заменить ее на `s` и вместо точки с запятой после `main` поставить `()` - все компилируется (работает ли верно - это вопрос другой). Еще раз - см. https://ideone.com/F1s2eI

Comment: Прошу заметить, что мне нужно, чтобы этот код работал в Jupyter Notebook, а так - я тоже могу сделать, чтобы работало в обычном компиляторе, но нужно чтобы работал в Jupyter Notebook, а там он выдает эту ошибку, вернее две одинаковые ошибки которые я указал выше. Мне дали такое задание, я его сделал, а если доделать чтобы работал в Jupytere то доп пункты будут.

Comment: Поправьте, если я ошибаюсь, но Jupiter Notebook - не компилятор, а IDE. И что в таком случае означает "чтобы работал в Jupiter Notebook"? 8-/

Comment: я сам мало чего понимаю, чем он является, 1-ый раз с ним работаю и не очень удачно. Когда я запускаю программу в Jupytere, короче вот ссылка на фото https://ibb.co/qYMHJxP